# Could not get unknown property 'incremental' for object of type org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KaptExtension

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle

This might be a simple one. I am trying to add below line in my build.gradle file,

```
kapt.incremental.apt=true
```

Getting below error after that,

Could not get unknown property 'incremental' for object of type org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KaptExtension.

I am using kotlin Version: 1.3.31-release-Studio3.3-1

What am I missing ?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I read the doc properly now and figured out that, it should be added in gradle.properties file

https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2019/04/kotlin-1-3-30-released/